# Asp.Net MVC 4 view model and domain model ids

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, design-patterns, domain-driven-design, viewmodel

Our system runs on multiple servers. All the tables in our system uses `GUID` as the `Primary Key` and `Foreign Key` fields. This is however our old system and it it going through a brand new rewrite.

The motivation to use `GUID` in the old system was for migration of data. It is perfectly reasonable to migrate items from one server to another. So using `int` as ids will be problematic when data gets migrated across.

Now the new system we want to use `GUID` as ids as well due to the migration factor. The new system will be written using DDD with MVC 4. Also we are using KendoUI for UI controls.

KendoUI by the looks of things does not support `GUID` int its grids for `Foreign Key`s. The column is blank when they are used.

Someone mentioned that my design is wrong and should not use `GUID` as the id. Is it really wrong to use `GUID` in the `View Model`? It would be really difficult to use `GUID` in the `Domain Model` and `int`in the `View Model`.

What is the better datatype to use in a system where the Ids are important across multiple servers in case of migration.

Or is migration of data a separate issue where I should be using API's and domain services to migrate data over, in which case using `int` as id is completely reasonable.

Can someone point me into the right direction please?

Comment: why not just have your view model treat your GUID as a string and then cast it back to GUID when persisting?

Comment: I tried this and It did not work with KendoUI. So `GUID` is the better way to  do it then?

Comment: what you use as your pk is up to you and what your system requires. why not contact Telerik and ask them about the issue you are having with GUIDs?

Comment: Well grids are part of the paid subscription. So need to get a licence. My trial expired. Just don't want to pay for something that does not work properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right with wanting to use GUIDs as IDs.  If your UI tools do not support GUID ids, use another tool.  I'd say that using vendor-specific UI tools is counter to the spirit of ASP.NET MVC anyway.  You should be able to find something free and open source which does what you need.

Under no circumstances should you be mapping GUID ids to int ids for the sake of your UI controls.  That will only lead to massive pain.

Comment: We have found a new tool to use. Back to basic `TwitterBootstrap MVC` with a nice 'FLATY` template.